# error al iniciar aplicacion en webLogic: NullPointerException at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext.deactivate

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

tengo un error #500 cuando inicio una aplicacion que tengo desplegada en WebLogic 12c, el error dice asi

Error 500--Internal Server Error

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractBoundContext.deactivate(AbstractBoundContext.java:71)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl.deactivate(HttpRequestContextImpl.java:68)
> at
> org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestDestroyed(WeldListener.java:121)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyRequestLifetimeEvent(EventsManager.java:429)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:30)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
> at
> weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
> at
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)  at
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

cabe destacar que esta aplicacion estaba desplegada en tomcat, y se
migro al servidor de aplicaciones de weblogic, he verificado los
archivos POM el persistence y no encuentro ningun detalle que haga
referencia a esos errores que arrojan el servidor, si alguien tiene
alguna sugerencia le agradezco

Comment: El error 500  esta especificad como "Internal server error", indica que existe un problema en el server el cual no permite cumplir la petición. Comentas que migraron a Weblogic, te aconsejo primeramente asegurar el funcionamiento del servidor es correcto.

Comment: como en el servidor todo estaba OK, decidí probarlo de forma local y me da el mismo error amigo, lo raro es que compila bien en el IDE e inclusive al momento de desplegar si algo estuviera mal no me permitiria el despliegue

Answer (score 1):

ya lo solucione eliminando del archivo pom la dependencia a la que hace referencia el error en este caso weldServlet

Answer (score -1):

Buenas tardes,

El error NullpointerException suele ser más un tema de código de la aplicación que error del servidor de aplicaciones. Por lo que he leido en tu post, el error se produce a la hora de inicializar la aplicación, es decir, una vez desplegada en Weblogic (asumo que sin errores), al levantar la aplicación y comenzar a recibir las peticiones, esta no se inicializa y te devuelve un 500.

En este sentido, el problema parece apuntar hacia la compatibilidad de la aplicación con Weblogic.

Mi recomendación es la siguiente:

-Asegurate que el classpath de Weblogic contiene todas las librerias que necesite tu aplicación. No suele funcionar bien si esas librerias las carga desde la aplicación.

-Asegurate que la versión de las librerias de tu aplicación no entren en conflicto con las librerias nativas de Weblogic.

-Asegurate que no tienes otros tipos de incompatibilidad, por ejemplo si usas persistencias es posible que la vesión JPA de Weblogic no coincida con la ultima versión que utiliza... mmm no sé, por ejemplo Spring o Rest, que es posible que sea más reciente.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: en efecto, es asi estimado, ella despliega sin ningun tipo de errores, al momento de iniciar la aplicacion lanza esa exception, voy a seguir tus recomendaciones, soy un poco nuevo en el manejo de weblogic, asi que empezare a indagar con respecto al classpath! saludos!

Comment: Animo y tranquilo. Como les gusta decir a los administradores de WAS, Oracle a la inversa es Elcaro. Si, es cierto, no nos vamos a engañar, pero ningún proveedor proporciona tanta información sobre sus productos de forma sencilla, directa. Facilita mucho la vida.

Comment: amigo @Manu como podria acceder desde la consola de administracion de weblogic a el classpath y ver que librerias posee? porque me inclino a que weblogic o no tiene dichas librerias como la weld o las posee pero no a la misma version que hace referencia mi aplicacion en el archivo .pom, espero puedas ayudarme, de antemano gracias

Comment: Buenas tardes. Perdon por la tardanza.
Para actualizar el  classpath de weblogic desde consola, hay que ir:

-Servidores ---> Pestaña general---> Inicio Servidor.


Ahi estan los parámetros de JVM (memoria) y el classpath. 

Un saludo.